# multiple keys in dict that are the same and are tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

I have sets of coordinates (in tuples that are the origins) that I am appending into a dictionary, followed by another tuple (the endpoint).

```
{(0, 0, 0):(10, 10, 10)}
```

There is a chance that multiple of the same coordinate for the origin will be put into the dict, followed by a different endpoint.

If I try this, they will overwrite, that is why I have tired the method from [here](http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=y107/wp2) where there are mutable objects. The only problem is that if I try and get the x, y and z from it, it turns out the object is not iterable.

Can someone please fix the code from there (will post what I am doing below) or give me a better way to do this? Thanks. (Still new to the mutable objects)

Code:

```
class coords(object):
    def __init__(self,part): 
        self.part = part
    def __str__(self):
        return self.part

d = {}
d[coords((0, 10, 0))] = (0 ,0 ,0)
d[coords((0, 10, 0))] = (0 ,1 ,0)
d[coords((0, 10, 0))] = (0 ,2 ,0)

for k in d:
    x, y, z = k
    print x,y,z

#Here I get the error: "TypeError: 'coords' object is not iterable" at the line "x, y, z = k"
```

Comment: Why not just store a dict of initial points to sets of target destinations? {(0, 0, 0):{(10, 10, 10), (2,1,6), etc}}. Whenever you initially add the point, create an empty set. Then add each target destination to the set. (A defaultdict can simplify some of the code as well).

Comment: Why not just do `x, y, z = str(k)`...or `k.part`

Comment: @Lalaland This is a good way to do it, I actually tried this way (just as a list instead) before but I had some troubles, but I got it to work, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a tuple subclass which has a different behavior concerning equality than the standard tuple.

```
class htuple(tuple):
  def __hash__(self):
    return id(self)
  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self is other
```

Now you can create `htuple`s like this:  `htuple((1,2,3))`

And these `htuple`s behave a little like `list`s (they are equal only on identity) and a mostly like `tuple`s (can be used as dictionary keys, can be iterated, etc.):

```
{ htuple((1,2,3)): (4,5,6),
  htuple((1,2,3)): (7,8,9) }
```

This is a *hack* (and I cannot stress this strongly enough).  But maybe in your special situation it is a solution you can live with.

Comment: If he actually has to use a dictionary, this is absolutely the right solution.

Comment: I like this one, even though it is a hack it works magically :)

Comment: @Linuxios Yeah, and *only* then.  The main idea behind a `dict` (to be able to index it with a value) is kind of disabled here because you only can use values to index the `dict` which come out of itself (maybe using `keys()` or `iteritems()` or similar).  And in most of these cases using a list of a tuple of these tuples (your solution) is much cleaner.

Comment: @Alfe: Thanks. It's good that we have both approaches for anyone else who comes to this question though.

Comment: @Linuxios It's gonna bite you. Coding should be more like science, not alchemy. I think you should change your model, not hack around the language to make it work for now. This changes semantics so your syntax work. IMO this was XY question. I think you were looking for multi-value dictionary. Well, you got warned by the author.

Comment: @luk32: I'm not the OP - I wrote the answer about changing the model to be a list of tuples :).

Comment: @luk32: However, you are right, and should probably address that comment to the OP. Hacks have their place, mostly in maintaining things that cannot be changed, but changing your data structure to be more natural will always help you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get what you need is to use a list of 2-tuples of endpoints:

```
endpoint_tuples = [((0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)), ((2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7))]
for start_point, end_point in endpoint_tuples:
  print start_point
  print end_point
```

If you need to find the endpoint for a certain start point `p`:

```
next(endpoints for endpoints in endpoint_tuples if endpoints[0] == p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can need to return a string from **str** not a tuple.Then in the loop just call the dictionary with the key returned from coords **str** method.

```
class coords(object):
    def __init__(self,part): 
        self.part = part
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.part)

d = {}
d[coords((0, 10, 0))] = (0 ,0 ,0)
d[coords((0, 10, 0))] = (0 ,1 ,0)
d[coords((0, 10, 0))] = (0 ,2 ,0)


for k in d:
   x, y, z = d[k]
   print x,y,z
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but I think this solution should be on the table. A classic (albeit very basic) way to solve having multiple values at any given key in a hash table is to use a list structure to enumerate all of the values with conflicting keys. Best part of this is that you get to use the `defaultdict` type, with no games/tricks.

```
d = {}
values = [
    (coords((0, 10, 0)), (0, 0, 0)),
    (coords((0, 10, 0)), (0, 1, 0)),
    (coords((0, 10, 0)), (0, 2, 0)),
]
for start, end in values:
    if start not in d:
        d[start] = []
    d[start].append(end)

for start in d:
    for end in d[start]:
        x, y, z = end
        print x,y,z
```

It's a lot less surprising to me than @Alfe's solution involving having multiple seemingly matching hash keys, and still lets you use the dict as a proper dict. (otherwise, what's the point?)

Also, you don't need to use a list to store your multiple values, I'm just using a list because it's simple/obvious. You can use a set type (for automatic de-duplication), or another dict if you think you can use a secondary hashing algorithm if you are going to have a lot of conflicts, and so on....

Comment: Sounds very much like Lalaland's comment right below the question ;-)  Add a part about using a `defaultdict` (which could be the best solution) and you'll probably get my upvote :)

Comment: Alfe is correct, this is basically Lalaland's solution (I didn't read comments -- oops!). I'm still leaving it so that the solution is represented in the list of solutions. @Lalaland, if you want to write up an answer sometime, I'll take this down.